# Select directories on client and upload info to node

Tags: node.js, browser, directory

I need to allow users to select directories locally (similar to the html file selector), with the path info uploaded to node.

I appreciate that sounds pointless, but it's to create a config file on the server that will match the client's requirements. So the user can select, say 'c:\documents' and 'd:\data\stuff' and have those paths passed as strings via http POST to the node (express) process.

How might I achieve this?

EDIT More info:

The data is for a client app, that works with the SaaS I'm working on. So the user (of which there will be many - I hope!) can make all their changes in one place, rather than having to configure settings in the portal, and then settings in the client GUI.

When the client app runs, it will pull the config (ie the directories it needs to process) from the server.

Comment: even if the client tells you where to store , how will your node service reach that client and store the data at the desired location? maybe i got the question wrong.
please provide more details about the requirement

Comment: Few questions to consider: Do you have only 1 user of the application? 
What if the user OS is different from the server OS. In linux based system, there would be no `C:\`

Comment: Added more info into the question. Re the OS, the server OS is Linux and the client will predominantly be Windows (almost exclusively), so that's where I'm focussing the first client release. The server already copes with the differences between windows and *nix formatted paths...